# Mismatched type in SML function with options

Tags: sml, option-type

The following is getting an error:

```
    (* Greetings, Earthlings! *)
fun greeting (some_name : string option) =
    "Hello there, " ^
    (if isSome some_name
    then valOf some_name
    else "you")
    ^ "!"
    
greeting("Tom")
```

The error is:

```
> $sml < main.sml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.78 [built: Thu Aug 31 03:45:42 2017]
- = stdIn:3.5-9.16 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: string
  in expression:
    "!" greeting
```

I can't figure out where there is a type mistmatch.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget semi-colon after `"!"`.  SML assumes here that `greeting("Tom")` is part of the function.  So it interprets `"!" greeting` as a function call.

Also your function argument is a `string option` so don't forget the `SOME` around `"Tom"`.  Here is the corrected code:

```ml
fun greeting (some_name : string option) =
    "Hello there, " ^
    (if isSome some_name
    then valOf some_name
    else "you")
    ^ "!";


print (greeting (SOME "Tom") ^ "\n");
print (greeting NONE ^ "\n");
```

Personally, I prefer using pattern matching in that situation, as it enhances readability in my opinion:

```ml
fun greeting (some_name : string option) =
    "Hello there, " ^
    (case some_name
      of NONE => "you"
       | SOME name => name)
    ^ "!";
```

Comment: An alternative to "remembering the semi-colon" is to not use the .sml file as a REPL: Rather than put a `greeting "Tom"` at the bottom, have a `val demo = greeting "Tom"` or a `val _ = print (greeting "Tom")`. So as long as your demo function applications are started like a value binding declaration, the semicolons can be omitted. So the only `;` that is necessary is the value infix operator.

Comment: Another fun idiom, rather than prepend `val _ = ...` to each REPL-like command, is to prefix *and* suffix your free-floating expressions with semicolons. So it's not necessary to end your declarations with semicolon as long as the look like `;print (greeting (SOME "Tom"));` since the `;` that separates declarations can occur multiple times in succession. The upside is that when you remove these lines again, since they are presumably for REPL testing, the remaining declarations won't contain unnecessary semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

This function is incidentally corresponds to the [two-fer exercise of Exercism.io](https://github.com/exercism/sml/tree/master/exercises/two-fer). Since my two favourite variants have not been show, I'd like to suggest either pattern matching directly in the argument of `greeting` or using a library function:

```
fun greeting NONE = "Hello there, you!"
  | greeting (SOME name) = "Hello there, " ^ name ^ "!"

fun greeting name =
    "Hello there, " ^ Option.getOpt (name, "you") ^ "!"
```

A reason for liking the first one is that it uses case-matching just like case-of, but with less syntax. And a reason for liking the second one is that it avoids duplication of the part of the string that is the same, and does so using library functions, so you can expect readers to have seen this before.

Comment: It is a community problem on the Coursera course for extra practice.

Comment: Good to know this!